# Переименовать значение, получаемое из XML

Tags: c#, wpf

Я получаю массив данных из xml, хочу переименовать определенные значения. Для Combobox это реализовано таким образом:

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cbNews.ItemsSource = _newsKeys;
        cbNews.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

_newsKeys:

```
_newsKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { AllRealms, "All News" },
            { "realm1", Settings.Default.server_name_wotlk },
            { "realm2", Settings.Default.server_name_cata },
            { "realm3", Settings.Default.server_name_mop },
            { "realm4", Settings.Default.server_name_wod },
        };
```

Не понимаю как переименовать эти данные в listbox, в котором есть Textblock.Text="{Binding Realms}"

Comment: Не совсем понятно, с какой целью вы хотите что-то переименовать. Для разных случаев есть разные подходы. Опишите подробнее, для чего вам это нужно.

Comment: @VladD, подробнее, на сколько можно, я могу показать в чате или скайп, если Вы не против. Скорее всего я не умею задавать вопросы(

Comment: News = newsSet.ExpressNews; листбокс.ItemsSource = newsSet.ExpressNews; В News содержится массив данных из xml, который прошел через десериализацию и разобрал по переменным объекты в xml. В самом листбоксе есть DataTemplate, в которой существует текстблок, получающий одну из переменных (Realms), полученые данные из xml так же подключены к комбобокс - cbNews.ItemsSource = _newsKeys;. Я хочу сделать то же самое, чтобы данные, которые получает комбобокс и переименовывает на значения, делал так же и листбокс

Comment: Окей, это уже интереснее. Ну, если у вас данные меняются в одном контроле, а другой это не подхватывает автоматически, то судя по всему, ваш тип данных, представляющий элемент списка, не имплементирует `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Я попробую создать чат, если получится.

Comment: Нет, не получается создать чат.

Comment: Попробую сама...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46907/discussion-between--and-vladd).

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае решилось таким образом

```
public class ExpressNewsItemViewModel : ExpressNewsItem
{
    public ExpressNewsItemViewModel(ExpressNewsItem item, IDictionary<string, string> correlations)
    {
        Item = new ExpressNewsItem();
        if (correlations != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Realms) && correlations.ContainsKey(item.Realms))
        {
            RealmsFriendly = correlations[item.Realms];
        }
        else
        {
            RealmsFriendly = item.Realms;
        }
    }
    public string RealmsFriendly { get; protected set; }
    public ExpressNewsItem Item { get; protected set; }
}
```

Благодарю всех, кто откликнулся!

Answer (score 0):

У  `Dictionary` есть методы: `ContainsKey()`, `ContainsValue()`, `TryGetValue()`
, свойства: `Keys`, `Values`, то есть вы всегда можете сформировать коллекцию ключей, либо коллекцию значений и отдать ее для ListBox. Также можете в заранее сформированном словаре осуществлять поиск нужного значения по ключу который может сопоставлен с данными из вашего xml.

Comment: Я не совсем Вас понимаю, с прошлой темой очень долго разбиралась (

Comment: Я из вашего вопроса понял, что на основании словаря вы хотите сформировать список для `ListBox`, вот я вам и подсказываю куда смотреть.

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать мне хоть примерный вариант? пробую вариант, как я делала с combobox, но так не работает (

Comment: Ну, видимо я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. Объясните, что вы имеете на входе и что хотите получить на выходе (с примером хотя бы в пару строк.).

Comment: `News = newsSet.ExpressNews;
                            листбокс.ItemsSource = newsSet.ExpressNews;` В News содержится массив данных из xml, который прошел через десериализацию и разобрал по переменным объекты в xml. В самом листбоксе есть DataTemplate, в которой существует текстблок, получающий одну из переменных (Realms), полученые данные из xml так же подключены к комбобокс - cbNews.ItemsSource = _newsKeys;.  Я хочу сделать то же самое, чтобы данные, которые получает комбобокс и переименовывает на значения, делал так же и листбокс

Comment: Берем ваш словарь `_newsKeys`, с помощью `_newsKeys.Keys` могу получить коллекцию состоящую из Realms, которую можно потом отобразить подключив ее к `листбокс.ItemsSource `. Когда пользователь выбирает в листбоксе, то по значению Realm вы ищете нужное значение в `_newsKeys`, вроде так?

Comment: Совершенно верно